# Volley Store Each Request In App Cache

Tags: java, android, json, caching, android-volley

```
class A {
RequestQueue mRequestQueue ;
public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstance){
mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
//Reuqest Call for JsonObject
mRequestQueue.add(new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, _filterUri, null, new Listener<JSONObject>() {

            public void onResponse(JSONObject jObj) {
                try { // a little bit code using jObj } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
            }
        }....//and error repsone listener as well.
}
```

So each Activity I do hold RequestQueue with the activity context . On RequestQueue hit always am getting one file storing my call and jsonObject in App Cache As Shown in Image. As much as i hit the RequestQueue ,Volley Store a file in cache .

[image]

1. Why Volley Store each file in cache and don't delete it ?
2. Am i doing wrong with calling RequestQueue according to Activity context?
3. I get lot of memory consumption with this volley cache is it ??
4. How do i optimise my http call with volley ?

Answer (score 2):

1. By default, Volley will cache every response received according to its HTTP cache headers. If the headers "say" cache, Volley caches, otherwise it doesn't.
2. I would use one `RequestQueue` for the entire app unless you have a good reason to use more than one.
3. I believe that the Volley cache is limited by default to 5mb. I'm not sure what you mean by a lot, but you can limit the cache size. **Note** that this is the internal disk cache used by Volley and not the memory cache that you need to provide to the `ImageLoader`.
4. I'm not sure what you mean by optimize an http call.

I would just like to remind you that Volley is open source, thus if you don't like the default behavior, you can change it to better suit your needs.